# ribbon controls

Tags: delphi, ribbon-control

How do I enable ribbon buttons which are disabled after clicking the *more commands* button in a quickaccessbar using Delphi?

Answer (score 8):

This is a known bug

Quality Central report 70342:

> When using Ribbon Controls, if one
>   adds a quick access toolbar, and then
>   at runtime chooses "More Commands" to
>   customize the quick access toolbar,
>   many (although not always all)  of the
>   action components in various ribbon
>   groups will become permanently
>   disabled.

Please see the report itself for more information: 
http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=70342

The report is still open, so I it may not have been solved in D2011 either, but Quality Central could be lagging behind a bit.

**Update**

The report states there is no work around, but Jack Sudarev posted one in the comments:

```
procedure TForm6.ActionManager1StateChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
UpdateActions(ActionManager1);
end;

procedure TForm6.UpdateActions(ActionManager: TActionManager);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  if not Assigned(ActionManager) then
    Exit;

  for i := 0 to ActionManager.ActionCount - 1 do
  begin
    (ActionManager.Actions[i] as TAction).Enabled := False;
    (ActionManager.Actions[i] as TAction).Enabled := True;      
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Note that [QualityCentral has now been shut down](https://community.embarcadero.com/blogs/entry/quality-keeps-moving-forward), so you can't access `qc.embarcadero.com` links anymore. If you need access to old QC data, look at [QCScraper](http://www.uweraabe.de/Blog/2017/06/09/how-to-save-qualitycentral/).

Answer (score 1):

This is what i did:

```
procedure TmainTranslatform.MyUpdateActions(ActionManager: TActionManager);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  if not Assigned(ActionManager) then
    Exit;

  for i := 0 to ActionManager.ActionCount - 1 do
  begin
  if (ActionManager.Actions[i] is TFileOpen)  then
  begin
    (ActionManager.Actions[i] as TFileOpen).Enabled := False;
    (ActionManager.Actions[i] as TFileOpen).Enabled := True;

  end;
  if (ActionManager.Actions[i] is TAction)  then
  begin
    (ActionManager.Actions[i] as TAction).Enabled := False;
    (ActionManager.Actions[i] as TAction).Enabled := True;
  end;
  end;
end;
```